# (plugin rollup-plugin-external-globals) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I use [rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) v3.2.2 as a module bundler in my React project. I added [rollup-plugin-external-globals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-external-globals) dependency to my project in order to handle some external libraries globally. After that, I started getting this error when I start my project with `rollup --config rollup.config.mjs -w` command:

```
bundles src/lib/index.js → dist/index.es.js, dist/index.js...
[!] (plugin rollup-plugin-external-globals) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
src/lib/index.css (1:0)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\my-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:20372:13)
```

The related configuration in **rollup.config.mjs** :

```
import externalGlobals from 'rollup-plugin-external-globals';


plugins: [
    ...
    externalGlobals({
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    }),
    ...
]
```

The related dependencies in **package.json** :

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "3.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-external-globals": "0.7.3",
}
```

According to the error log, the unexpected token error is related to the `index.css` file.
But, I get the same error even if the content of `src/lib/index.css` file is empty, too.
What should be done to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the order of plugins in the rollup config. The `rollup-plugin-external-globals` plugin should be somewhere after both `@rollup/plugin-babel` and `rollup-plugin-postcss` plugins. In my case, I got the error fixed when the content of my **rollup.config.mjs** was like this:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import externalGlobals from 'rollup-plugin-external-globals';
...

plugins: [
    ...
    babel({
        babelrc: false,
        babelHelpers: 'bundled',
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind', '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
        presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }], '@babel/preset-react'],
    }),
    resolve({
        mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext', 'module', 'main'],
    }),
    postcss({
        extensions: ['.css'],
    }),
    externalGlobals({
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    }),
    ...
]
```